# replacing last word of string using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
    var str = "Demo Docs Version 1.0.1";

    var got = str.split(" ").splice(-1)[0]

    str = str.replace(got, "testing");

    console.log(str);
```

I can replace last word if there is space in between but how can i replace my last word when there _ in string ?

```js
var str = "Demo-Docs-Version-1-0-1";

    var got = str.split(" ").splice(-1)[0]

    str = str.replace(got, "testing");

    console.log(str);
```

Comment: May be ```var got = str.split(" ").pop();```

Comment: Then `got.push("testing").join(" ");`

Comment: Sorry i have updated my question

Comment: Your edit completely changes your question, for which there is already an answer. Like, you asked one question, and now you're asking an entirely different one.

Comment: About the question update... No change, just split by the underscores instead of by spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

`str = str.replace(/(?!.*(\s|_)).*/, "testing")`

Comment: hi @0brine can you help me i have updated my question once again and want to remove numbers with `testing` can you help me last time ?

Comment: `str = str.replace(/(?!(-| |_))(\d|-|\.)+\s*$/, "testing")`
this will replace only numbers at the end, the number at the end can look like this `1-0-1` or `1.0.1` and there has to be either a "-", " " or "_" in front of the number